# Prevent users from creating Schedules for jobs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to restrict the development users from creating new schedules for SQL Agent jobs. They should be able to create a job and pick one of the available schedules, but should not be able to create a new schedule.

I have a bunch of developers creating SSIS packages that need to be scheduled off business hours. I am now faced with either having to do that myself, or risking the possibility of someone scheduling a major task during business hours and slowing down the DEV server noticeably. 
Is this possible?

Any alternate solutions also welcome.

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out one way.

```
DENY EXECUTE ON sp_add_schedule to <USER>
```

Will this lead to any other complications?

Raj